# Is it safe to put the output of 'strace' online?

Tags: anonymity, file-upload, risk-management, confidentiality

For debugging purposes, one might be asked to put the output of `strace` for some process online, i.e. attached to a bug report.

Is this safe in general?  Under what circumstances is this safe or unsafe, and how would I process a strace-logfile to make sure it is safe to put online?

(I suppose it might depend on the application)

Comment: (Not sure how to tag this.  Please improve.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`strace` has the potential to include any data processed by the application.  If reading/writing sensitive data from standard in, a UI, network, or disk, it's possible that that information is included in the `strace` log.  If at all possible, try to reproduce bugs without processing sensitive data in the process when you're going to post logs.

Since you didn't specify what kind of application you're dealing with, this is about as extensive as an answer that I can give.